# Spring RESTful Как отфильтровать JSON ответ?

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, filter, rest

Возникла проблема с JSON ответом от RESTful сервиса.

Использую:

> SpringMVC - 4.2.4.RELEASE,
>   Spring Data - 1.9.2.RELEASE,
>   Hibernate - 5.0.2.Final,
>   MySQL Connector - 5.1.38,
>   Jackson JSON - 2.6.5,
>   Spring HATEOAS - 0.19.0.RELEASE

Имеется сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "films")
public class Film implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8647833898589302685L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id_film", nullable = false)
    private int idFilm;

    @Column(name = "alternative_name", length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String alternativeName;

    @Column(name = "original_name", length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String originalName;

    @Column(name = "year", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "SMALLINT(4)")
    private short year;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description = "";
}
```

К ней репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface FilmRepository extends JpaRepository<Film, Integer> {
}
```

Сервисе и его реализация:

```
public interface FilmService {
    public List<Film> getFilms(int offset, int limit);
    public Film getFilm(int id);
}

@Service
public class FilmServiceImpl implements FilmService {

    @Autowired
    private FilmRepository filmRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Film> getFilms(int offset, int limit) {
        Pageable pageRequest = new PageRequest(offset, limit);
        Page<Film> page = filmRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
        return page.getContent();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Film getFilm(int id) {
        Film film = filmRepository.findOne(id);
        return film;
    }
}
```

А также контроллер:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/films")
public class FilmController {

    @Autowired
    private FilmService filmService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    params = {"offset", "limit"},
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<Resources<Film>> getFilms(@RequestParam(value = "offset") int offset, 
                                                @RequestParam(value = "limit") int limit) {
        List<Film> films = filmService.getFilms(offset, limit);

        Resources<Film> filmsResource = new Resources<>(films);

        int prev_offset = offset - 1;
        if (prev_offset >= 0)
            filmsResource.add(linkTo(methodOn(FilmController.class).getFilms(prev_offset, limit)).withRel("prev"));
        filmsResource.add(linkTo(methodOn(FilmController.class).getFilms(offset, limit)).withSelfRel());
        filmsResource.add(linkTo(methodOn(FilmController.class).getFilms(offset + 1, limit)).withRel("next"));

        return new ResponseEntity<>(filmsResource, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id_film}",
                    method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public HttpEntity<Resource<Film>> getFilm(@PathVariable(value = "id_film") int id) {
        Film film = filmService.getFilm(id);

        Resource<Film> filmResource = new Resource<>(film);
        filmResource.add(linkTo(methodOn(FilmController.class).getFilm(id)).withSelfRel());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(filmResource, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

На запрос: `GET /films?offset=0&limit=2`
Приходит ответ:

```
{
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/entity/films?offset=0&limit=2"
    },
    {
      "rel": "next",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/entity/films?offset=1&limit=2"
    }
  ],
  "content": [
    {
      "idFilm": 1,
      "alternativeName": "Властелин Колец: Братство Кольца",
      "originalName": "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring",
      "year": 2001,
      "description": "Сказания о Среднеземье - это хроника Великой войны за Кольцо Всевластья, войны, длившейся не одну тысячу лет. Тот, кто владеет Кольцом, получает власть над всем миром..."
    },
    {
      "idFilm": 2,
      "alternativeName": "Властелин колец: Две Крепости",
      "originalName": "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers",
      "year": 2002,
      "description": "Братство кольца распалось, но надежда еще жива. Фродо и Сэм продолжают свой путь в Мордор, к Роковой горе. Мерри и Пиппин попадают в плен к Урукхаям, новой породе орков..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Собственно вопрос: Как отфильтровать такие поля как: `"originalName"`, `"description"`? Ведь когда пользователь хочет получить список фильмов, ему не обязательно отсылать полную информацию о фильме, как в JSON выше! Ответ должен быть такого плана:

```
{
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/entity/films?offset=0&limit=2"
    },
    {
      "rel": "next",
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/entity/films?offset=1&limit=2"
    }
  ],
  "content": [
    {
      "idFilm": 1,
      "alternativeName": "Властелин Колец: Братство Кольца",
      "year": 2001
    },
    {
      "idFilm": 2,
      "alternativeName": "Властелин колец: Две Крепости",
      "year": 2002
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: преобразовать json с помощью парсера в нужный json?

Comment: я просто подумал, может ли сам сервис по этому запросу, отдать нужный мне json отфильтровав ненужные поля?

Comment: ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете указать аннотацию `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` для тех полей, которые не должны передаваться через REST-сервис. Например:

```
@JsonIgnore
@Column(name = "description", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String description = "";
```

Фильтрация при этом будет осуществляться на стороне сервиса, а не на стороне клиента. С одной стороны, это приведет к небольшой экономии за счёт снижения затрат на сериализацию, передачу по сети, и десериализацию на клиенте. С другой стороны, если исключённые поля потребуются в другой части клиентского приложения, их уже нельзя будет получить через тот же сервис. Потребуется альтернативная сущность `Film` и альтернативный сервис `/films`.

**UPD**
Вообще, создание отдельных сущностей для чтения списка записей ("короткой") и для чтения конкретной записи (полной) - довольно распространённая практика. Даже для сущностей средней сложности можно получить значительную экономию ресурсов при таком подходе. Количество информации, которую можно отобразить в виде списка, практически всегда ограниченно несколькими полями, и вычитывать для этого всю запись вместе со всеми её связями - довольно расточительно, особенно с учётом того, что все лишние данные будут вычитаны впустую. В конкретно Вашем случае, это не критично, т.к. ваша сущность не тянет даже на среднюю сложность. Но как только в ней появятся связанные записи, например, жанры, актеры, отзывы и т.п., то вопрос о разделении на две сущности станет намного актуальнее.

Comment: Да, я знаю про эту аннотацию, но проблема в том, что этот запрос `GET /films?offset=0&limit=2`, не должен возвращать игнорируемые поля, а этот `/films/{id}` должен!

Comment: Отлично - две разных точки доступа у вас уже есть, значит осталось сделать "укороченную" сущность (например, `FilmShort`), в которой не осуществлять маппинг ненужных полей вообще. Т.е., копируем `Film` в `FilmShort`, удаляем поля `originalName` и `description` вообще, а в `GET /films` и в `filmService.getFilms` осуществляем чтение не `Film`, а `FilmShort`

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ! Пытался так сделать, но видимо, до конца не смог допилить, в будущем попробую еще раз, может что и выйдет с этого. А разве при создании сущности первая (`ShortFilm`) не будет переписана второй (`Film`)?

Comment: Нет, для `JPA` это будут две абсолютно независимые друг от друга сущности (если вы намерено каким-либо образом не свяжете их). А при выборке из БД, генерируемый SQL-запрос в операторе `SELECT` не будет содержать полей `original_name` и `description` в случае выборки сущности `FilmShort`. Для того, чтобы избежать дублирования кода для двух похожих сущностей, можно вынести общие поля в базовый класс `FilmAbstract` и указать аннотацию класса `@MappedSuperclass`, а в классах `FilmShort` и `Film` наследоваться от `FilmAbstract`. Поля, вынесенные в `FilmAbstract`, удалить из `Film`.